# Vaadin | Unable to initialize com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListene

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, vaadin, vaadin24

I had a Kotlin Spring Boot application that supported Backend APIs only with Spring Boot.
I tried to add Vaadin Dependencies and the application broke with

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:199) ~[vaadin-spring-24.3.2.jar:na] at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:223) ~[vaadin-spring-24.3.2.jar:na] at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na] at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:223) ~[vaadin-spring-24.3.2.jar:na] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4452) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4892) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na] at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na] at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:913) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8] at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0] at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0] at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:489) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0] at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0] at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]`

Now the dependencies I have added are :

`implementation("com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter:24.3.2") implementation("com.vaadin:vaadin-core:24.3.2")` 
with java 17 and Spring Boot 3+ on Vaadin 24
and I cannot resolve the issue...!!

Can someone help with this?

[image]

I tried adding these files and frontend folder from the sample application but nothing worked.
Also tried running npm innstall and generated node modules.

Nothing worked :(